# Notifications style for ckeditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

recently I implemented a file upload system into my ckeditor but when I want to display notifications they appears without style.
[image: Notification]

Do ckeditor come with default classes for these or I need to create manually? If I need to create them, how can I make them? I know notifications have "cke_notifications" and "cke_notifications_typeofnotification" classes. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using a third-party skin that wasn't updated to provide [CKEditor 4.5+](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Released) compatibility. Some new features that were introduced back then (notifications and the "busy" state) required skin authors to introduce some changes - it seems the author of this skin did not do it.

Here is the [complete guide explaining what needs to be done to update the skin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/skin_sdk_compatibility_with_ckeditor_4_5). You may wish to contact its author and ask for these changes to be introduced and try to fix it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot :DD. It works fine! Note: I'm using Flat skin, one available when you download ckeditor xD.

Comment: I know that the author did not provide a link to any website/repository, but you can also download the skin ZIP archive from [its Add-ons Repository page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/flat) to get the source code and work on this.